# Syntax error when updating columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the following code to update columns:

```
UPDATE user_profiles 
    SET range = '20', colResize = 'flex' 
    WHERE uid='472';
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute SQL : SQL UPDATE user_profiles SET range = '20', colResize = 'flex' WHERE uid='472'; failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'range = '20', colResize = 'flex' WHERE uid='472'' at line 1
```

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Use backticks to escape the name or use another column name.

```
SET `range` = 20
```